# How can I block HTTP session timeouts in my Seam applications?

Tags: java, session, timeout, seam

We have a rather restrictive architecture where we have a portal-like Seam application which launches further 'child' Seam applications inside an iFrame.

We have a problem where the portal application's HTTP session times out even though the 'child' applications are still being used.  We need to keep the HTTP session timeouts to keep the site secure.  We've been chewing at this problem for a while now and found ourselves down a number of dead ends.

So the questions is how can we block HTTP session timeouts in our portal application based on activity in 'child' applications?

Comment: Couldn't you just increase the session timeout to some very long value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the HttpSession timeout variable on the server to a very high value

Comment: Setting a value of zero would also disable the session from timing out.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the child applications do a HTTP call on a special "keepalive" URL (which can be a simple servlet just returning `200 OK`) in the portal application. These requests could either be sent out via AJAX by the client or you could do it on the server side using HTTP sub requests, based on child activity.